# Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW does not create a new transaction in Spring with JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have the following scenario. I am using JPA, Spring:

```
@Autowired
SampleService service;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void PerformLogic(LogicData data) throws SIASFaultMessage
{
    SampleObject so = createSampleObject();

    try{
        .//do some logic to persist things in data
        .
        .
        persistData(data);
        .
        .
        .


        updateSampleObject(so);     
    }
    catch(Exception){
        updateSampleObject(so);     
        throw new SIASFaultMessage();
    }

}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public createSampleObject()
{
    SampleObject so = new SampleObject();

    .
    .//initialize so
    .

    service.persist(so);        
    return so;
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public updateSampleObject(SampleObject so)
{               
    service.persist(so);        
    return so;
}
```

When everything works fine, data is persisted in database without problems. However, when an exception is thrown, I need that the method **updateSampleObject(so)** persist the information in the database. This is not what is happening. If an exception is thrown the method **updateSampleObject** gets rolled back also, which is not what I need. I need that these two methods (***createSampleObject*** and ***updateSampleObject***) get persisted all the time, no matter whether an exception got thrown or not.
How can I achieve this?

Moreover, if I anotate the methods **createSampleObject** and **updateSampleObject** with:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
```

the idea is that an exception is thrown and I get no exception thrown. Where is the problem? Analizing the logs I see this line:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  ==> Creating new transaction with name [com.test.PerformLogic]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT....
```

which means this transaction is created, but I see no hint of the other transaction.

This is the part of my configuration file for Spring regarding transactions

```
<bean id="myDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="cu.jpa"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hdm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property value="/META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml" name="persistenceXmlLocation"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaPersistenceUnit"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Spring transactions are proxy-based. Here's thus how it works when bean A causes a transactional of bean B. A has in fact a reference to a proxy, which delegates to the bean B. This proxy is the one which starts and commits/rollbacks the transaction:

```
A ---> proxy ---> B
```

In your code, a transactional method of A calls another transactional method of A. So Spring can't intercept the call and start a new transaction. It's a regular method call without any proxy involved.

So, if you want a new transaction to start, the method `createSampleObject()` should be in another bean, injected into your current bean.

This is explained with more details in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained).

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I will take a closer look to Spring documentation. Do you know if there is a way for the transactions to work not on proxy-based, but on the method?

Comment: @AlfredoA. It's possible if you use AspectJ load-time weaving to byteweave your code, thereby obviating the need for proxies as mentioned above.  That way, transactional method foo() of class A can call transactional method bar(), also of class A, and bar() will run inside its own transaction.  For more info on this, consult the Spring Framework documentation linked above.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I searched a lot when transaction is committed as I have 2 different transactions where one is dependent on other's result. It worked with "Required" & "Requires_New" but only when I put then in different beans.

Comment: have AspectJ-based transaction any disadvantages? when should I use proxy and when AspectJ style?

Comment: Thanks for ending several hours of frustration. Flowers should be on the way.

Comment: I have a question, (after all this years :) )
Does this means that the private methods are always executed in the transaction of the method that calls them (if that method is public and annotated with @Transactional)? For example in code above does createSampleObject(), persistData(data); and updateSampleObject(so);  are executed in the scope of the transaction that is open at PerformLogic(LogicData data) method?

Comment: @JB Nizet you made my day!

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that since both methods are in the same bean, the Spring's AOP does not have a chance to intercept the create/updateSampleObject method calls. Try moving the methods to a separate bean.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was it. I would mark it as correct, but I just read the other one first.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a bean for the same class(self) and use bean.api(which requires requires_new).
It works.

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases, even if you have `service a -> service b` and you have a `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `service b`  method(which needs to be `public` by the way!), locking rows etc may fail.
This is usually if `auto-commit: false` is not specified in your spring(usually hikari pool) datasource configuration. The reason is that any `select for update` or similar statements are executed immediately and the database does not lock the row.