# hibernate 4 handle unique index exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, constraints

I have a system based on hibernate 4. I have an unique constraint in a table and need to handle it the following way:

```
try{
    getMyService().create(myobj);
}catch(PersistenceException p){
  //constraint fails
    myobj.setConstraintColumn("new non unique value");
   getMyService().create(myobj);//should save it
}
```

unfortunately I can't change the design of the system so I need just to figure it out this way.

**EDIT**

I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

The code of create method:

```
 public E create(E entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.refresh(entity);
        return entity;
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure what specific question you have.  You are saying that you would prefer that the system assign a unique value, but are forced to catch the ConstraintViolation when it happens.  At that point you are prepared to assign a new value and try again.  What have you tried, and what issues are you having?

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. So, let me explain one by one. 
First of all, take a look at

[Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW does not create a new transaction in Spring with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480480/propagation-requires-new-does-not-create-a-new-transaction-in-spring-with-jpa)

Then, for example we have a class and method like:

```
public class MyClass{
   @Transactional
   public void myMethod(){
      ....
   }

}
```

So, first of all lets consider that myMethod is in it's own transaction completely, because transactions are AOP based, and it will be committed when appropriate aspect will fire, but only after method completes, throws exception, etc. So we can't partially commit, partially rollback, rollback incompletely,etc. So, we need to do the following:

1. Start big outer transaction
2. Start a new nested transaction, try to insert a record.
3. If nested transaction will fail, it will be rolled back, but the outer one will still be running.
4. If the first nested transaction failed, then start a new nested transaction and insert a record with new data, which will prevent ConstaintViolationException from being thrown.

So, in this case, we create a class:

```
public class ServiceHelper{
    @Transational(proparation = **Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW**)
    public void tryConstraint throws MyConstraintException{
        try{
           //insert
        }catch(ConstraintViolationException e){
           throw new MyConstraintException(e);
        }catch(Exception ex){
           throw new Exception(ex);
        }
    }

    @Transational(proparation = **Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW**)
    public void insertWithNoConflict throws Exception {
        //Set new data
        //insert, if still CVE or anything other, just throw it , or leave it for unchecked exceptions then
    }


}
```

And our service:

```
public class MyService{
@Autowired
private ServiceHelper serviceHelper;

@Transactional(propagation = **Propagation.REGUIRED_NEW**)
public void createWithCheck(){
   try{
      serviceHelper.tryConstraint();
   }catch(MyConstraintException e){
       serviceHelper.insertWithNoConflict();
   }
 }
}
```

But there is still a weird situation because I need to use MyService methods for records creation in ServiceHelper, but I can't obtain them there because it will cause circular injections, so I have to get them via services factory like:

```
MyService service = (MyService)ServicesFactory.getInstance().getBean(MyService.BEAN_ID)
```

And I don't like it. But this approach works, I checked it today.

We should know 2 things: first of all we can't do anything with a transaction inside a method, we can't start there any new transaction, etc. A transaction context is relevant to method completely, it will still be there before a method ends. And the second thing is required_new doesn't work when we launch the method from the method of the same proxy class.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear where your transaction boundaries are. 
When the exception is thrown, you will need to:
1)  Ensure that the first transaction is closed (it should be, but not sure - see if you get a nested transaction trying #2 alone)
2)  begin a new transaction before you are able to persist/flush again (and subsequently commit that).

Comment: Why the first transaction should be closed? What if I want to suppress this exception? Why not?

Comment: It is my understanding that when an exception is thrown (the unique constraint will throw an exception which you can't control or suppress) the transaction is invalidated.  In that state you have no other choice but to start again.

Comment: Thanks, but I caught this exception, don't understand how it gets invalidated though.

Comment: I suspect in the Hibernate code they invalidate the session, and then throw the exception.  By the time you catch it, it is already invalidated.  They leave it to you to rollback anything open (if necessary).  Let me know how you make out...