# Transaction rollbacked previous transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jta

I have this weird behavior with transactions in Spring.

I have two classes:

The service class that is first called by doGenericServiceStuff (by another object that already posses a transaction):

```
@Service("myService")
public class ServiceClass {

    public void doGenericServiceStuff(Object someBean){
        BusinessI business = BusinessFactory.getBusinessForObject(someBean); //Here, returns the commonBusinessClass bean 
        business.doGenericBusinessStuff(someBean);
    }

    /*@Transactional (readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)*/
    public void firstOperation(Object o){
        //multiple database insert and stuff
    }

    /*@Transactional (readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)*/
    public void secondOperation(Object o){
        //also multiple database insert and stuff
    }
}
```

Then the CommonBusinessClass that calls some of the ServiceClass' methods:

```
@Bean("commonBusinessClass")
public class CommonBusinessClass implements BusinessI{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myService")
    protected ServiceClass = null;

    @Transactional(rollBackFor=Exception.class, Propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public Object doGenericBusinessStuff(Object o){
        service.firstOperation(o);
        service.secondOpertion(o);
        //There can be stuff here in other BusinessClass
        return o;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Obviously, I don't manipulate `Objects` like that and I don't call my method `doGenericStuff()`. However, ServiceClass does call CommonBusinessClass, which in turn, calls the ServiceClass. Maybe it's bad design, maybe it's the reason it's not working, but this is what I have for the moment.

The methods in `ServiceClass` are not Transactional (thus the comments), and the `doGenericBusinessStuff()` is (with `Propagation.MANDATORY`).

The new requirement is that if `secondOperation()` fails (and rollbacks) `firstOperation()` should be commited. So I added `@Transactional` for `firstOperation()` and `secondOperation()` (those in comment). I was expecting it to work normally (an exception in `secondOperation()` wouldn't rollback what has been done in `firstOperation()`), but it does not. However if I remove the `@Transactional` on `doGenericBusinessStuff()`, it works.

Is this behavior normal, or there is something else that comes into play in my real application that I didn't put here (because I simplified it) ? Why would the newly created transaction be linked to each other in any way ? Any ideas of what might happen ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the context of a transaction. If you mark a method as transactional, it means that every operation inside that method will be considered as one thing. If everything works ok then the transaction is committed but if something goes wrong then the whole transaction is rollbacked.

In you case you have:

```
  @Transactional(rollBackFor=Exception.class, Propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public Object doGenericBusinessStuff(Object o){
        service.firstOperation(o);
        service.secondOpertion(o);
        //There can be stuff here in other BusinessClass
        return o;
    }
```

So, if `service.firstOperation(o)` fails then the whole transaction is rollbacked and it's the same for `service.secondOpertion(o)`. If `service.secondOpertion(o)` fails the all the operations inside `doGenericBusinessStuff` will be tollbacked.

Edit: The REQUIRES_NEW might not work in some cases, if your using JtaTransactionManager for example:

> NOTE: Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on
>   all transaction managers. This in particular applies to
>   JtaTransactionManager

From http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html

Comment: Alright, so marking both firstOperation as `@Transactional` with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` won't make it an independant transaction (that won't rollback if `doGenereicBusinessStuff()` does)  ?

Comment: If you use Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW then Spring will create a new independent transaction.  http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-propagation-tutorial

Comment: But if all of your methods are in the same class. doGenericBusinessStuff and firstOperation, then Spring transactional will not create a new transaction. Spring is not able to handle this scenario implicitly. Any annotation on the called method would be ignored (since the call happens on 'this' rather than on the Transaction Proxy) 
You need to switch to AspectJ to handle such scenario's. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480480/propagation-requires-new-does-not-create-a-new-transaction-in-spring-with-jpa

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, I added `@Transactionnal(Propagation.NEW_REQUIERED)` to `firstOperation()`, and it still rollbacks when `secondOperation` throws an Exception. But it should not, because it's a different transaction from the one declared in `doGenericBusinessStuff`,right ?  However if I remove the `@Transactional(Propagation.MANDATORY)` from CommonBusinessClass, `firstOperation()` does not rollback when `secondOperation` throws an Exception.

Comment: "NOTE: Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers. This in particular applies to JtaTransactionManager"  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html

Comment: Yes that's it, I'm using JtaTransactionManager and it does not creates a new transaction with the REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: What appserver are you using ? I'll give it a try on tomcat/mysql

Comment: I'm on a tomcat, Postgresql, and it's actually the org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager (Spring 4.2.3).

Comment: hmmm, JpaTransactionManager  is not JtaTransactionManager. Probably that's the problem